# Reading files with nested while loops

Tags: python

This function is part of a larger class, this functions purpose is to make a dictionary using the first lines last element as key and `s_d` as value. The `c` is supposed to be used for something else. When i print `new_dict` i get the desired result but the loop keeps running

```
def extract(filename):
f = open(filename)
new_dict={}
c = ''
l = f.readline().strip()
while l :
    first = f.readline().strip()[-1]
    s_d = f.readline().strip()
    l = f.readline().strip()
    new_line= f.readline().strip()
    while new_line != 'FIN' :
        c = c + new_line
        new_line = f.readline().strip()
    new_dict[first]= s_d
    print(new_dict)
```

This function has to be done this way, with two while loops.How can i make the function stop running after it runs out of lines

BTW
the text file looks like:

```
IDS
ID 0
text(small description of item)
text(long description)
text(long desc second line)
FIN
ID 1 
same as before
```

Comment: Why not just `for l in f:`?

Comment: its supposed to be done with the while loops, sine later im supposed to make an object that involves first, s_d and c. It would take alot of code with for loops

Comment: That's not actually a reason.

Comment: Well i told you its supposed to be done this way. plus this functions finished just needs an adjustment

Comment: But how does the kind of loop help or hinder you making an object? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: im not sure how to implement it with using for loops. This method seemed simple, if you can fix it with for loops be my guest

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value returned from readline() function is an empty string. If it is, you have reached the last line and you can break.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

After adding `s_d` to dict update `l` as `l = new_line` . This will make sure that `while l:` always checks with the last line read from the file.

Comment: same problem, the loop keeps going